# Не срабатывают WordPress тэги

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование, wordpress-плагины

Создаю галерею NextGEN, но на странице выводятся только её тэги:

```
[gallery link="file" ids="3176,3177,3178,3179,3180,3181,3182,3183,3184"] [gallery link="file" columns="2" ids="3164,3136" orderby="rand"]
```

В чём может быть проблема?

PS - это в записях блога, а на странице блога галерея работает. -__-

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Надо выводить контент через the_content(); и обязательно в цикле.

Comment: Не обязательно через the_content() и не обязательно в цикле. Работает потому, что the_content() выполняет шорткоды в контенте. А если вы выводите контент как так `echo $post->post_content` то никакие шорткоды не срабатывают. Чтобы срабатывали, можно выводить таким образом: `echo do_shortcode( $post->post_content );`